# Database connection is not closing properly

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, database-connection

I am using C# linq to sql application and my application is running 24*7 in servers. Now i am facing the issue database connections they are not closing so active connects reach to 200 and more. I used using syntax everywhere I am dealing the database directly.

But this is not solving my problem. Please check and let me know what best i can do for this.

Provider always disabled my database.

```
using (DataClassesDataContext DbContext = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
  return DbContext.tblApiLinks.FirstOrDefault(U => U.ProviderName == ProviderName);
}


using (DataClassesDataContext DbContext = new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            tblApiLink Apilink = new tblApiLink();
            Apilink.ApiUrl = Url;
            Apilink.ApiKey = Key;
            Apilink.ProviderName = Provider;

            DbContext.tblApiLinks.InsertOnSubmit(Apilink);
            DbContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

New Edits

Case 1. Please check these code it returning a table. Does this effect to close the connection?

```
public tblApiLink getData()
{
    using (DataClassesDataContext DbContext = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
  return DbContext.tblApiLinks.FirstOrDefault(U => U.ProviderName == ProviderName);
}
}

tblApiLink api =  getData();
```

Case 2. If I used like this tblApiLinks lst= dbContext.tblApiLinks;
I think this will not close the connection and they will be active all time.

Case 3. Is there any way to close all sleeping connection which is active from long time and not in use.

Comment: Please add example code of how you query the DB.

Comment: `"Please check and let me know ..."` - Check *what*, exactly?

Comment: @PankajMishra: I see nothing structurally wrong with the code shown.  The problem you're observing may not be as simple as what's presented in this code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158315/discussion-between-pankaj-mishra-and-david).

Answer (score 0):

In your "case 1" try to set a variable that stores what you want to return, and return the value after the using block is closed.

Example:

```
    tblApiLink returnData = null;
    using(DataClassesDataContext DbContext = new DataClassesDataContext())
    {
        returnData = DbContext.tblApiLinks.FirstOrDefault(U => U.ProviderName == ProviderName);
    }
    return returnData;
```

Side note: The type `tblApiLink` isn't correctly named according to convention, I suggest you refactor it if possible.

Case 2: I don't understand what you mean.

Case 3: You could use a singleton that handles connections and closes them, but the proper way to do this is disposing the connections that are no longer active. If you really want to kill active connections your best bet would be on the server, either manually or storing a procedure that you can call later on.